# Definition of Sub-Lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

In reference to [Sub-lattices and lattices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310926/sub-lattices-and-lattices)

In Wikipedia, it's given that-

> A sublattice of a lattice L is a nonempty subset of L that is a
>   lattice with the same meet and join operations as L.
>
> That is if L is a lattice and $M ≠ {\displaystyle \varnothing } $  is
>   a subset of L such that for every pair of elements a, b in M both a ∧
>   b and a ∨ b are in M, then M is a sublattice of L

In Discrete Mathematics and It's Application - Kenneth Rosen, $7^{th} \ Indian \ edition$, it's given that -

> A sublattice of a lattice L is a subset $S \subseteq L$ such that if
>   $a,b \in S, \ a \wedge b \in S \ and \ a \vee b \in S. $

I understood that $1^{st}$ condition of $M \subseteq L$ to be a sub-lattice is that- for every pair of elements a, b in M both a ∧ b and a ∨ b should present in M.

But is it necessary that M should have the same meet and join operations as L?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is. This is implied in the second definition; the symbols $\land$ and $\lor$ are being used to refer to the operations in $L$.

Comment: Got it. Means I should find $a \wedge b$ and $a \vee b$ with respect to L and then see whether they belong to M or not.
Am I right?

Comment: @user9014873: Yes, that's right.